# How do I check if a string array is full

Tags: java

I want to check if there is a value assigned to every part of my string array e.g. If my string array is String[8], I need to check if there is 8 different values in the string array.

Comment: Does every value need to be different from each other?

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate through each element of the array and check if it is null, if none is null then the list is full.

```
boolean isFull = true;
for(String s : yourarray) {
    if(s == null) {
        isFull = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If each value needs to be different then you have to have nested loop. (A bit unclear in the question)

```
boolean isFull = true;
for(String s : yourarray) {
    for(String t : yourarray) {
        if(s == null || s.equals(t)) {
            isFull = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody that cares to explain the down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
boolean isFull = true;
for(int i = 0;i<yourarray.length;i++)
{
    if(yourarray[i] != null && !yourarray[i].isEmpty())
    {
        isFull = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you compare strings with `==`?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut my apologies. Have edited

Comment: The string is null before it has been initialised.

Comment: @imulsion no need to apologize :) I would rewrite the condition to: `if(yourArray[i] != null && !yourArray[i].isEmpty())`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Thanks :) I just wrote a minimalist condition for summary, but that is a useful addition

Comment: This does not work either, if any value is null then the code ends with isFull = true even though the array isn't "full". It needs to be yourarray[i] == null.

Comment: @spydon I don't know how you reached that conclusion. For a start, as Thomas pointed out, you don't compare strings with `==`, and the `break;` statement beaks out of the loop when the condition is not met.

Comment: oh, well it depends on what is required. If you want to check that the array should only contain not null and not empty strings, then you need to invert the if statement to `yourArray[i] == null || yourArray[i].isEmpty()`. However this seems not to be what the TE wants and it is closed now anyway- so no need to make up a discussion here I feel.

Comment: @imulsion you can compare string objects with ==, .equals is used when the content of different string objects are compared.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the characters that make up the string are all different. For this, I recommend the following methods: String#length, String.charAt, String.indexOf and a loop over all characters, i.e. from 0 to n-1, where n is the string length.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: Here `str_array` (just initialized for example purpose) is the string array, and `empty_indexes` is the list of indexes of String array that are empty.

```
        String str = "This is the example string";
        String[] str_array = str.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Integer> empty_indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
            if (str_array[i] != null) {
                if (str_array.equals("")) {
                    empty_indexes.add(i);
                }
            } else {
                empty_indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
```